# CSS Stylesheet with several different classes under the same parent class

Tags: css

When writing a css stylesheet I'd like to know if there's a way to group several different classes inside another parent class.

Example, I have this:

```
.ParentContainerClass .class1 {

}

.ParentContainerClass .class2 {

}

.ParentContainerClass .class3 {

}

// ......many classes here

.ParentContainerClass .class1200 {

}
```

I'd like to know if there's a way that I could write something like this:

```
.ParentContainerClass {

    .class1 {

    }

    .class2 {

    }

    .class3 {

    }

// ......many classes here

    .class1200 {

    }

}
```

This is just to avoid having to go class by class (I have many) and qualify each of them individually with the "ParentContainerClass".
Is there a way?

Thank you

Comment: Look into SCSS https://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Nesting has been around in CSS preprocessors (e.g. `SCSS`/`LESS`) and CSS-in-JS tools (e.g. `emotion`/`styled-components`), if you're open to using them. Otherwise, native CSS nesting is being discussed. See [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/css-nesting-specificity-and-you/) and [this Log Rocket article](https://blog.logrocket.com/native-css-nesting/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
.ParentContainerClass .class-item {}
.ParentContainerClass .class-item.class1 {}
```

.class-item your main selector for all subs. .class1 for more spesific usage.

Comment: He wants to avoid having to add .ParentContainerClass multiple times.

Comment: yes, edited my solution